# Release a new version of iphone app in selected countries

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes-store

I am bit confused regarding release of new version of my app. There are few queries if someone can help me:

-I have first version of my app in all countries. Is it possible to release new version suppose 1.1 in only US.

-Suppose i can release 1.1 in US, is it possible to release the third version for some other country say Australia and have same version number that is 1.1

How to maintain version numbers if release versions of my app is separate for separate countries.

I hope i am clear with my dought. Forgive if my language is confusing.

Comment: Why closed. I am really confused and stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its not possible to have multiple versions of same application for different countries.
E.g: If version 1 is released to whole world, 
now version 1.1 is released for the same app (You are updating and not adding another app) and selected only US then 
Result - US will have version 1.1 and rest of world would not have your app.

To satisfy your case, I would suggest to keep different applications based on the countries you want to release in. It would be tedious to maintain same code base for different countries but I think it may solve your problem.